# urllib2 javascript redirect issue

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

```
import urllib2,urllib

data = urllib.urlencode({"username" : "usr", "password" : "pass", "lang" : "eng", "usertype" : "cashier", "submit" : "Enter"})
req = urllib2.Request("https://website/index.php", data)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
response = opener.open(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

OUTPUT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "/h383/list.php";</script>
```

So I want to reach list.php any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First, try delivering a stern lecture to the webmaster about graceful degradation and web standards.

If that fails, then you ultimately have two options:

1. Extract the redirection location using a regular expression.  (Pro: This is easy.  Cons: This won't work if the redirection URL is built using JavaScript, as opposed to showing up as a single string literal.  Additionally, minute changes in the script -- even the addition of whitespace -- are likely to break your expression.)
2. Run the script through a JavaScript runtime, providing `window` and `window.location` objects, and catching the assignment to its `href` property.  (Pros: This will allow for JS-built URLs to work, and is fairly future-proof.  Cons: This is probably over-engineering, and won't be a simple task.)

Comment: first solution fails because every page has javascript redirection. Moving on to second

Comment: @snagcheol: what do you mean "*every* page has javascript redirection"? If every page redirected you could never get anything done. And if it's just lots, I still don't see that that's a problem unless you can't parse it. Anyway, what are you trying to do?